# pySpintax not found inside env, despite having it inside the pipfile

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a script that I want to run within a separate environment. It runs perfectly fine when I don't define an env (so just in a cmd prompt on windows).

But whenever I run it inside of an env, it doesn't work.

```
from pySpintax import spin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pySpintax'
```

I have it inside my pipfile file, so doesn't really make sense to me. But I might be missing something...

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
pyspintax = "==10.0"
```

Comment: Have you installed it in your env also ?

Comment: I have. But granted, I intend this script to create multiple env's, one for every "thread" I want to run it in. It works fine with basic modules, but for some reason, the pySpintax one doesn't pick up. even though it's globally installed on the device, and is included in the pipfile.